# Can I enable migration and update database using code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using entity framework code first approach and have following model and db context.

```
public class Patient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }

  public class PatientContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Patient> Persons { get; set; }
    }
```

Now to have the model created in database I have to Run `Enable Migration` and if any changes then have to run `Update database` using package manager console.

But is there any way I can do that using code. So when ever some one run console application it will create all table schema.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           //Code to Create my tables 
           //Something similar to enable migration and update database
        }
    }
```

I can have a record created inside main app and that will create the table structure, but creating an record to create table structure seems redundant. Also , if there are any mode changes, following code will throw an exception.

Is there a better approach?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (PatientContext pcontext = new DatabaseMigApp.PatientContext())
            {
                pcontext.Patients.Add(new Patient() { FirstName = "Steve",Id = 1});
                pcontext.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
```

Comment: See https://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. You will have to run Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations from package manager console first, so that it generates a Configuration class as follows:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DatabaseMigApp.PatientContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(DatabaseMigApp.PatientContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you may update the Program.cs as follows to automatically migrate to the latest version based on your model changes:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (PatientContext pcontext = new DatabaseMigApp.PatientContext())
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<PatientContext, Configuration>());
            pcontext.Database.Initialize(true);
        }
    }
}
```

If you do not wish to use automatic migrations and generate them manually (for more control), you could turn off the automatic migrations and add-migration each time you change your model. The code in the program.cs would still suffice to update your database when you run the console application.

Read more about automatic migrations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735(v=vs.113).aspx)